# Pyspark -No module named coverage_daemon

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to execute this simple code in my dataframe:
`import ast rddAlertsRdd = df.rdd.map(lambda message: ast.literal_eval(message['value'])) rddAlerts= rddAlertsRdd.collect()`
But I´m getting the error below:

[image]

Versions:

- Spark: 3.3.1
- Hadoop: 2.7
- Python: 3.7
- Pyspark: 3.3.1
- Py4j: 0.10.9.5
- OpenJDK: 8

Can it be a problem related to compatibility versions? Appreciate your help!

In order to solve the problem I tried to change Spark environment variables in my Dockerfile.
This is what I have in my Dockerfile:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** No idea what could be wrong but giving you a little more about the possible cause while reading the source code. Hope this helps.

---

The only place with `coverage_daemon` is [python/test_coverage/conf/spark-defaults.conf](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.3.1/python/test_coverage/conf/spark-defaults.conf#L21) which (as you may've guessed already) is for test coverage and does not seem to be used in production.

It appears that for some reason [python/run-tests-with-coverage](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.3.1/python/run-tests-with-coverage#L44-L45) got executed.

It looks as if you're using Jupyter environment that seems misconfigured.

Comment: this error only appear when i execute pyspark rdd code
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.html

Answer (score 1):

I had faced this issue as well. Apparently I had copied `spark-defaults.conf` file from python/test_coverage/conf/spark-defaults.conf to the `$SPARK_HOME/conf`, which included the setting

`spark.python.daemon.module coverage_daemon`

I had to comment out this configuration while executing Pyspark RDD code, to fix it.